# How to create custom guage chart as shown in the below image with highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to create custom guage chart as shown in the below image with highcharts?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating such a chart in Highcharts is possible, but it requires combining the `solidgauge` series responsible for the background with an appropriate stroke and the `gauge` series with a modified source code to draw a circle instead of a pointer.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7vfkrjgz/ 
Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render